# Regarding the problem that the setOnImageAvailableListener callback method cannot be triggered

Tags: java

During the camera preview process, the callback method for processing the preview image cannot be triggered normally.

```
private void openCamera(boolean isBack, int width, int height) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestCameraPermission();
        return;
    }

    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (null == activity || activity.isFinishing()) {
        return;
    }

    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

    try {
        if (!mCameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");
        }

        if (isBack) {
            mCameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];

            mPreviewSize = new Size(1440, 1080);

            mBackImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight(), ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, mMaxImages);
            mBackImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(mOnImageAvailableListenerBack, mBackgroundHandler);

            Log.v(TAG, "openCamera mCameraId=" + mCameraId);
            manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallBack, mBackgroundHandler);
        } else {
            mCameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[1];

            mPreviewSize = new Size(1080, 720);

            mFrontImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight(), ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, mMaxImages);
            mFrontImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(mOnImageAvailableListenerFront, mFrontgroundHandler);

            Log.v(TAG, "openCamera mCameraId=" + mCameraId);
            manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallFront, mFrontgroundHandler);
        }
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListenerBack = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
@Override
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
reader.acquireNextImage();
}
};

```
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListenerFront = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        reader.acquireNextImage();
    }
};
```

Demos on the Internet are all written like this. Why can't my code trigger the callback onImageAvailable()? What's the reason?

Comment: mFrontImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(mOnImageAvailableListenerFront, mFrontgroundHandler);
mFrontPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mFrontImageReader.getSurface());
After writing this way, the callback method can be triggered，why?